# About Java subinterface subtype

Tags: java, interface

This seems a basic java question.

I have one interface, `Pipeline`, which has a method `execute(Stage)`.

Then I create a sub interface to extend from `Pipeline`, say `BookPipeline`, I like the method to be `execute(BookStage)`.

`BookStage` extends from `Stage`.

Seems this kind of definition could not pass java compile.

Any suggestion on that?

Comment: What's the compiler error message? What's your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to consider using generics.

```
public interface Pipeline<T extends Stage> {
     public void execute(T stage);
}

public interface BookPipeline extends Pipeline<BookStage> {
     @Override
     public void execute(BookStage stage);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the declaration of `execute` in `BookPipline` redudant?

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes, it's there for the sake of the example

Comment: Gotcha, I don't need to override it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @Jeffrey wrote as a possible solution, it is important to understand why you cannot do it.

Assume you had an interface `Pipeline` with a method `execute(Stage)`, and an extending interface `BookPipeline` with `execute(BookStage)`.

Also assume you have some class `Conc` that implements `BookPipeline`.

Consider the following

```
Pipeline p = new Conc();
p.execute(new Stage());
```

What will happen? It will be unsafe! 

Java wants to avoid it, and thus prevent this situations from the first place.

The rule is **an extending class/interface can add behavior, but not reduce it**.

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on @amit 's answer, the code snippet is unsafe as the `Conc.execute` method takes a `BookStage` as a parameter and this would be trying to squeeze a `Stage` in place of that (and of course, not all `Stage`s are `BookStage`s).

However, imagine we wanted to go the other way, that is, make the parameter type of the `BookePipeline.execute`a *super* type of `Stage`, such as `Object`.

So just to clarify, we would have:

```
interface Pipeline
{
  void execute(Stage s);
}

interface BookPipeline extends Pipeline
{
  @Override
  void execute(Object s);
}
```

And where `Conc` implements `BookPipeline`:

```
Pipeline p = new Conc();
p.execute(new Stage());
```

This would, in theory, be safe because Liskov Substitutability has not been violated - we could safely pass a `Stage` into any implementation that took a `Stage` parameter or greater. This is known as *contravariance*. Java does not support *contravariant* argument types, however there are [languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sather) that do.

Your original question relates to *covariant* argument types which is unsafe for the reasons specified (however strangely enough, a language called [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language)) allows this).

Java does however support covariant *return* types. Imagine `Pipeline` had a

```
Stage getAStage();
```

it would  be perfectly legal for  `BookPipeline` to override this method like so:

```
@Override
BookStage getAStage();
```

Then imagine we had:

```
public void someMethodSomewhere(Pipeline p)
{
  Stage s = p.getAStage();
  //do some dance on Stage
}
```

Assuming we had some class `Donc` which implemented `Pipeline` and overrode `getAStage()` exactly as it is defined in `Pipeline` (so still returning `Stage`), both of these calls are OK:

```
someMethodSomewhere(new Conc());
someMethodSomewhere(new Donc());
```

Because we can always put a `Stage` or anything less (e.g. `BookStage`) in a variable of type `Stage`.

So to reword the rule to relate specifically to method overriding, **an extending class/interface that overrides methods, can only make those methods *more general* in what they accept and *more specific* in what they return.** (although in the case of Java, only more specific return types are allowed.)

Just remember, PECS - Producer Extends, Consumer Super (Joshua Bloch, Effective Java)